# Timezone issues with MySQL and clj-time

Tags: mysql, jdbc, clojure, timezone, sqlkorma

I have a table in MySQL.

`create table demo ( theDate datetime );`

I insert two dates, one in daylight saving time, one not.

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as t])
(require '[clj-time.coerce :as coerce])
(require '[korma.core :as k])

(k/insert :demo (values {:theDate (coerce/to-sql-date (t/date-time 2014 01 01))}))
(k/insert :demo (values {:theDate (coerce/to-sql-date (t/date-time 2014 06 01))}))
```

From my MySQL client it looks like the right values have gone in:

```
mysql> select * from demo;
+---------------------+
| theDate             |
+---------------------+
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2014-06-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

When I select with Korma (I don't imagine Korma is doing anything relevant on top of JDBC), I get a timezone difference in the non-daylight saving time date.

```
=> (k/select :demo)
[{:theDate #inst "2014-01-01T00:00:00.000000000-00:00"}
 {:theDate #inst "2014-05-31T23:00:00.000000000-00:00"}]
```

And when I select the dates:

```
(map #(-> % :theDate coerce/from-sql-date t/month) (k/select :demo))
(1 5)
```

Whereas I would have expected to get `(1 6)` (I deliberately put the dates on a month boundary to illustrate). The same thing happens when I use `date` rather than `datetime` MySQL type.

What am I missing? How do insert `[(t/date-time 2014 01 01) (t/date-time 2014 06 01)]` and get back `(1 6)`?

Comment: You should be storing timestamps as UTC, and converting them to local when you need to display them.

Comment: or store unix timestamp as long

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The result you get depends on the default timezone for the JVM. You can  fix that via whatever mechanism the host operating system gives you.But in my experience it's generally better to force the JVM to a known value explicitly.

This is achieving with a property on the command line, or in leiningen `project.clj`

```
:jvm-opts ["-Duser.timezone=UTC"]
```

Comment: _to add some google keywords/a back link_: my problem was that I would store a UTC in a MySQL db, and I would query for it in clojure, it would suddenly be a local time, and no amount of coercion would get it interpreted as UTC. I asked `clj-time` maintainers to drop a note of this in their docs somewhere: https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time/issues/233

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this as well and ended up using korma's `exec-raw` and specifying:

```
at time zone 'utc' as theData
```

to actually get back the correct time zone.

Comment: Thanks! sw1nn's answer solved it, but I thought that `exec-raw` didn't work with selects? I get `SQLException Can not issue executeUpdate() for SELECTs  com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException (SQLError.java:1074)` when I `(k/exec-raw "select * from demo")`.